# sqlcmd: how to make the :r command to display errors in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

When I execute the following command in SQL Server Management Studio it says the query completed with errors at the bottom but shows no errors. How can I force it to show what errors it encountered?

```
:r $(file)
```

Comment: Sorry,are you really sure you are executing this in SSMS? It looks like some console-related magic

Comment: @Sergey it's SQLCMD syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#supported-sqlcmd-syntax

Comment: Why would you even want to run `:r $(file)` in SSMS? It's specific to [sqlcmd's own command interpreter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility#sqlcmd-commands). Asking a question like this is similar to asking why SSMS's `GO` batch separator doesn't work via pyodbc or any other SQL driver.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I now execute sqlcmd commands from Command Prompt and save errors in the file and it works fine. But for some reason when there are too many errors and the file ends up being large it is not saving anything. Weird.